# How do Python properties work?

Tags: python, properties

I've been successfully using Python properties, but I don't see how they could work. If I dereference a property outside of a class, I just get an object of type `property`:

```
@property
def hello(): return "Hello, world!"

hello  # <property object at 0x9870a8>
```

But if I put a property in a class, the behavior is very different:

```
class Foo(object):
   @property
   def hello(self): return "Hello, world!"

Foo().hello # 'Hello, world!'
```

I've noticed that unbound `Foo.hello` is still the `property` object, so class instantiation must be doing the magic, but what magic is that?

Comment: See also: [How does the @property decorator work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17330160/562769)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

As others have noted, they use a language feature called descriptors.

The reason that the actual property object is returned when you access it via a class `Foo.hello` lies in how the property implements the `__get__(self, instance, owner)` special method:

- If a descriptor is accessed on an *instance*, then that instance is passed as the appropriate argument, and `owner` is the *class* of that instance.
- When it is accessed through the class, then `instance` is None and only `owner` is passed. The `property` object recognizes this and returns `self`.

---

Besides the [Descriptors howto](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html), see also the documentation on [Implementing Descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors) and [Invoking Descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) in the Language Guide.

Answer (score 26):

In order for @properties to work properly the class needs to be a subclass of **object**. 
when the class is not a subclass of **object** then the first time you try access the setter it actually makes a new attribute with the shorter name instead of accessing through the setter.

The following does **not** work correctly.

```
class C(): # <-- Notice that object is missing

    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        print 'getting value of x'
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        print 'setting value of x'
        self._x = x

>>> c = C()
>>> c.x = 1
>>> print c.x, c._x
1 0
```

The following will work correctly

```
class C(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        print 'getting value of x'
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        print 'setting value of x'
        self._x = x

>>> c = C()
>>> c.x = 1
setting value of x
>>> print c.x, c._x
getting value of x
1 1
```

Comment: One should be aware that as of Python 3, inheritance from _object_ is no longer required.

Comment: Or more precisely, in Python 3, classes inherit from _object_ by default so this need not be written in the code explicitly.

Comment: Why can `x` be allocated to 2 separate methods? Because of the decorator? Either way, why? @TimothyVann

Answer (score 15):

Properties are [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html), and descriptors behave specially when member of a class instance.  In short, if `a` is an instance of type `A`, and `A.foo` is a descriptor, then `a.foo` is equivalent to `A.foo.__get__(a)`.

Comment: Actually, they also seems to work with an old-style class (in Python 2.7). But thanks for the link, will read.

Comment: Note that the method signature for `__get__()` is incorrect. It has two arguments (in addition to self). Otherwise well explained.

Comment: @larsmans: From the linked page: "Note that descriptors are only invoked for new style objects or classes."  I also remember that I once tried them for old style classes.

Comment: @Tim: The second argument is optional.

Comment: @Sven:  Maybe true for how properties are implemented, but they are always passed when the descriptor is invoked. Language Guide: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors

Comment: @Sven: then Guido must be playing tricks on me. They really work for old-style classes in my Python 2.7.1.

Comment: @Tim: Read carefully the page your link points to, for example the part "Direct call".  Or look at the prototype of `__get__()` given on the page linked in my post.  The second argument **must** be optional, that's part of the protocol.

Comment: @larsmans: I did some quick tests.  The type of the descriptor itself must be a new-style class, otherwise it won't work.  The class containing the descriptor does not matter.  The above quotation could be read in either way.

Comment: @Sven: I think we're both right. In the spec for `__get__()` in the previous section, it says "owner is always the owner class", and when the descriptor is actually invoked as a descriptor, it is always passed. It's not that important--I was mostly trying to clarify how it could produce a different result when accessed via the class.

Answer (score 3):

The `property` object just implements the descriptor protocol: http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html

Comment: I certainly understand the reasoning behind a dw in this case, both this answer and the one accepted are devoid of a *real* explanation, and are just basically links. While this is sufficient in some error-solving cases, it seems the OP was looking for a human explanation on the subject.