# Is it Pythonic to classify objects by empty child classes?

Tags: python, enums

Sorry about the title, I'm not sure how to word this question in a more general sense. I'm working on a [brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) parser. The language has 8 kinds of tokens, which I currently represent with the following classes:

```
# Types of lexical tokens
class Token: pass
class IncPtrToken(Token): pass
class DecPtrToken(Token): pass
class IncByteToken(Token): pass
class DecByteToken(Token): pass
class OutputByteToken(Token): pass
class InputByteToken(Token): pass
class LoopStartToken(Token): pass
class LoopEndToken(Token): pass
```

In another language I would probably use an enumeration to represent the different types, but this seems like a reasonable alternative in Python.

I have read that there are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python) of representing enums in Python, but I think this style is suitable because some of these entities may carry additional data with them. For example, when representing types of nodes in a parser, a node like a loop would contain a member with the nodes inside the loop.

Comment: Yes. The same thing is done for the Exception class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319615/proper-way-to-declare-custom-exceptions-in-modern-python

Comment: @user2357112 I know it's extreme overkill, but I kind of want to structure it like a classic compiler with the lexer, parser and code generation stages.

Comment: Python lacks real enumerations. What you are doing is perfectly normal.

Comment: Python 3.4 has enums now. you can check the [PEP435](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435)

Comment: @Hassek True, but some of these may need to store data at some point.

Comment: My bad, didn't read the whole post, if you want to add additional data I would probably use Enums and a class with `type` (the enum) and a list of nodes for example, instead of using that many classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python gains an official Enum class in 3.4.

If you are using Python between 2.4 and 3.3 check the [enum34 backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34).

It is possible to [add other behavior and state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17911188/208880) to a custom Enum class as well.

Comment: Accepting because they are appropriate in this case. Is it acceptable to alternate between enums and classes in the same program for when one fits the requirements better?

Comment: Of course.  Python is not a bondage language -- use whatever makes sense for each case.

Answer (score 1):

Type :

```
import this
```

(also named PEP 20) explains shortly what is pythonic.

"If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea."

I don't know how you intend to do your brainfuck interpreter. I suppose you don't intend to put the specific functions (related to what the given ...Token does) inside the ...Token class.

I would use functions or, if they are empty, a list to do so, replaced by an enum as soon as Py 3.4 is released.

In a nutshell : hard to explain? Keep thinking!