# Enum with attributes in Python

Tags: java, python, parameters, constructor, enums

I am a Java developer, but now I am working on a Python project. Is it possible to write an enum whose constructor has attributes?

I would do it this way in Java.

```
public class Main {

    private enum Planet {
        MERCURY(3.303e+23, 2.4397e6),
        VENUS(4.869e+24, 6.0518e6),
        EARTH(5.976e+24, 6.37814e6),
        MARS(6.421e+23, 3.3972e6),
        JUPITER(1.9e+27, 7.1492e7),
        SATURN(5.688e+26, 6.0268e7),
        URANUS(8.686e+25, 2.5559e7),
        NEPTUNE(1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);

        private final double mass; // in kilograms
        private final double radius; // in meters

        Planet(double mass, double radius) {
            this.mass = mass;
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " radius: " + radius + ", mass: " + mass;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Planet planet : Planet.values()) {
            System.out.println(planet);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: ummm your example code is in the official docs ... https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#planet ... (note that enum is only available in python3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Joram noted, your Planet example is [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#planet).

If you want to know how to add a plain constant to an `Enum`, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911188/is-it-possible-to-define-a-class-constant-inside-an-enum/18035135#18035135).

Oh, and `Enum` [has also been backported](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34).