# How do define an attribute in Python 3 enum class that is NOT an enum value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

How to define an attribute in a Python 3 enum class that is NOT an enum value?

```
class Color(Enum):
    red = 0
    blue = 1
    violet = 2
    foo = 'this is a regular attribute'
    bar = 55  # this is also a regular attribute
```

But this seems to fail for me. It seems that Color tries to include foo and bar as part of its enum values.

EDIT:
Lest you think I'm not using Enum in a way that's intended... For example, take the official Python documentation's example enum class Planet (docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#planet). Note that they define the gravitational constant G within the surface_gravity() method. But this is weird code. A normal programmer would say, set that constant G once, outside the function. But if I try to move G out (but not to global scope, just class scope), then I run into the issue I'm asking about here.

Comment: Why do you need this? You can't do it like that, no.

Comment: There is no built-in facility that regards some attributes as enums and others as 'regular'. There is no difference between `foo` and `bar` in your enum as far as Python is concerned. Just because you used a different type object for the value makes no difference.

Comment: Well, because one of the reasons for the existence of these fancy Enum classes is that they can be regular classes, you know, with methods and such, and eventually, I get to a point where I need a class-level constant!

Comment: Class-level 'constants' are always members of the enumeration if defined in the class body; Python doesn't have 'constants' anyway. I'd stick to a global instead.

Comment: It is possible to have class-level constants in an `Enum` -- see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18035135/208880).  There is no protection against reassigning the "constant" value, though -- just like in regular classes.

Comment: @EthanFurman I don’t really understand why you feel the need to go to a *closed* question 5 months after closing it, linking explicitly to *your* answer again (which is also the accepted answer on the close target), *and downvoting* the two answers to this closed question when those answers may be a bit complicated but nevertheless both provide a *working* solution for the problem. Are you that overconfident that *your* solution is the *only* acceptable solution for this requirement?

Comment: @poke: I'm reviewing all the [enums] [python] answers, and up/down-voting where appropriate.  I don't agree with your characterization of the `Enum` data type in this instance (you have up-votes from me in other instances).  Had somebody else written my solution I would have acted the same to these answers/comments.

Answer (score 13):

The point of the `Enum` type is to define enum values, so non-enum values are theoretically out of scope for this type. For constants, you should consider moving them out of the type anyway: They are likely not directly related to the enum values (but rather some logic that builds on those), and also should be a mutable property of the type. Usually, you would just create a constant at module level.

If you really need something on the type, then you could add it as a class method:

```
class Color(Enum):
    red = 0
    blue = 1
    violet = 2
    bar = 55

    @classmethod
    def foo (cls):
        return 'this is a not really an attribute…'
```

And using the `classproperty` descriptor from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5191224/216074), you can also turn this into a property at class level which you can access as if it was a normal attribute:

```
class Color(enum.Enum):
    red = 0
    blue = 1
    violet = 2
    bar = 55

    @classproperty
    def foo (cls):
        return 'this is a almost a real attribute'
```

```
>>> Color.foo
'this is a almost a real attribute'
>>> list(Color)
[<Color.red: 0>, <Color.blue: 1>, <Color.violet: 2>, <Color.bar: 55>]
```

Comment: @EthanFurman well, yes. Work days can become quite busy very quickly. I don’t remember the context of that quote any more, and it’s really difficult to know what I was thinking *5* months later… but I guess what I was trying to say is that when you have a member out in the open on the type object, the public interface just begs to access and modify it. That’s not really a good idea for constants. Constants should be somewhere safe, or at least clearly marked as constants.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

When building an `enum.Enum` class, **all** regular attributes become members of the enumeration. A different type of value does not make a difference.

By regular attributes I mean all objects that are not descriptors (like functions are) and excluded names (using single underscore names, see the [*Allowed members and attributes of enumerations* section](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#allowed-members-and-attributes-of-enumerations)).

If you need additional attributes on the final `enum.Enum` object, add attributes *afterwards*:

```
class Color(Enum):
    red = 0
    blue = 1
    violet = 2

Color.foo = 'this is a regular attribute'
Color.bar = 55
```

Demo:

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class Color(Enum):
...     red = 0
...     blue = 1
...     violet = 2
... 
>>> Color.foo = 'this is a regular attribute'
>>> Color.bar = 55
>>> Color.foo
'this is a regular attribute'
>>> Color.bar
55
>>> Color.red
<Color.red: 0>
>>> list(Color)
[<Color.red: 0>, <Color.blue: 1>, <Color.violet: 2>]
```

Comment: The `Enum` metaclass does support @eng's use-case via the descriptor protocol (in other words, Python supports it, I didn't have to do anything extra).

Comment: @EthanFurman: yes you did, you had to create a descriptor, which in my book is certainly doing something extra. Which is a nice and clever trick, but that doesn't make my technically incorrect. Was my answer really that unhelpful to deserve a downvote?

Comment: Ah, I meant I didn't have to do anything extra when creating the metaclass to support this use-case.  Due to the ugly hack of assigning attributes after class creation and the wrong information in the comments, I downvoted.  My hope was that an overall -1 score would warn future seekers not to use these answers.

Comment: @EthanFurman: We can easily clean up the comments; just flag those you think should go. They are not part of the answer. You mention assigning attributes after class creation as a solution in your own answer.

Comment: Yes, I did mention assigning attributes after class creation in my answer; I also mentioned why it is not a good solution.