# Using enum for gamestates in Python

Tags: python, enums, pygame

I'm currently working on a game in python with pyGame and want to use enums for the different states(gamestate, levelstate etc,) in the game.

I have inherited my own GameState class from Enum class as seen in the code below.
I have the enum members set up (mainMenu, inGame etc...) and then put them into a list named allGameStates.

I get a problem when trying to iterate through the list containing all the gamestates in the setter function. I get:

> AttributeError: 'GameState' object has no attribute 'allGameStates'

Also, while hovering over the list variable allGameStates it says:

> inferred type: GameState

Shouldn't it be a list type?

```py
class GameState(Enum):

    mainMenu = 'MainMenu'
    inGame = 'InGame'
    pause = 'Pause'
    exit = 'Exit'

    allGameStates = list([mainMenu, inGame, pause, exit])
    curgamestate = allGameStates[0]

    def __init__(self, newgamestate, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

        self.gamestate = newgamestate

    @property
    def gamestate(self):
        """Gets the current game state"""
        return self.curgamestate

    @gamestate.setter
    def gamestate(self, state):
        """Sets the current game state to another"""
        try:
            for gamestates in self.allGameStates:
                if gamestates.name == state:
                    self.curgamestate = state

        except ValueError as err:
            print(err.args)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your problem is one of timing and one of understanding<sup>1</sup>:

- The enum member names (`'mainMenu'`, `'pause'`, etc.) are not actually converted into `Enum` members until *after* the class is completed; this means that any class-level references (`'allGameStates' = ...`) are referring to  strings.
- `self.curgamestate = ...` -- this is setting the current game state on an instance (an `Enum` member), not on the class -- so what the "current" game state is can (and will!) be a confused mess.  What you need there is `self.__class__.curgamestate = ...`
- finally, a rule of thumb for what gets converted into an `Enum` -- anything that is a simple name assignment.  So, not only are `mainMenu`, `inGame`, `pause`, and `exit` converted into `Enum`s, but so is `allGameStates` and `curgamestate`<sup>2</sup>.

Some hints:

- once `GameState` is built, `list(GameState)` will give you the (correct) list of members
- `self.gamestate` is the same as `self.name`
- `self.allGameStates` should just be `self.__class__` (unlike normal classes, an `Enum` class is iterable)

--

<sup>1</sup> see [When and where to use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22594360/208880) for some ideas on how to use `Enum`

<sup>2</sup> see [Define a class constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17911188/208880) for ways to have simple name assignment *not* get transformed into `Enum` members