# Typing simple descriptor example as Enum class constant with mypy

Tags: python, enums, mypy, python-typing, python-descriptors

I wanted to implement [a class constant in an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18035135) using a descriptor with a type hint that mypy would recognize. My first step was trying the docs [Simple example: A descriptor that returns a constant](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#simple-example-a-descriptor-that-returns-a-constant).

```py
class Ten:
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None) -> int:
        return 10


class A:
    x = 5      # Regular class attribute
    y = Ten()  # Descriptor instance


reveal_type(A.x)  # Revealed type is "builtins.int"
reveal_type(A.y)  # Revealed type is "builtins.int"
```

Afterwards, applying the above simple example to an Enum has mypy recognize the type as a `Literal` instead of an `int`:

> Revealed type is "Literal[my_module.B.y]?"

```py
from enum import Enum


class Ten:
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None) -> int:
        return 10


class B(Enum):
    One = 1
    Two = 2

    y = Ten()  # Descriptor instance


reveal_type(B.y)   # Revealed type is "Literal[my_module.B.y]?"
```

Am I doing something wrong or Is this a mypy bug? If it's a bug is there a workaround?

Comment: Possibly related [issue 12494](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12494) leads to [PR 12669](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/12669).

Comment: In case someone thinks of using a cast below the descriptor it won't work because of *"Attempted to reuse member name in Enum"*

Comment: "Possibly related issue 12494 leads to PR 12669." Yup. I just need to spend some time making my approach in that PR a little less hacky and disgusting :)

Comment: @AlexWaygood I'd love to help out if I had the time and expertise, but if you need someone to test it let me know.