# How can I get the value of a <property object at 0x...> in Python

Tags: python, astropy

I am new to Python and using Python 2.7 on Windows I am using Astropy library, but when I want to view an attribute on the following class:

```
>>> astropy.cosmology.FlatLambdaCDM.Ok0
```

it returns:

```
<property object at 0x7fa2c7e206d8>
```

Same for other attributes on that object.  How do I access the numerical values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do Python properties work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193556/how-do-python-properties-work)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know anything about astropy myself, but from your description it soulds like `Ok0` is a property of the `FlatLambdaCDM` class. You're usually not supposed to try to access properties on a class directly, but rather through an instance of the class.

Try something like:

```
# create an instance
instance = FlatLambdaCDM()  # the constructor may require some arguments

# access the property on the instance
instance.Ok0
```

I don't know what arguments (if any) the `FlatLambdaCDM` class constructor requires, so you may need to add some more stuff to get a workable object.

Comment: That's exactly right.  See the intro docs to http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/cosmology/index.html