# Trouble understanding private attributes in classes and the class property method in Python 3

Tags: class, python-3.x, namespaces, decorator, private-members

This class example was taken from [here](http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property).

```
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0):
        self.temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    def get_temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self._temperature

    def set_temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        print("Setting value")
        self._temperature = value

    temperature = property(get_temperature, set_temperature)
```

The idea here is that when we create an instance of Celsius and set the temperature attribute (e.g. foo = Celsus (-1000) ), we want to make sure that the attribute is not less than -273 BEFORE setting the temperature attribute.

I don't understand how it seems to bypass `self.temperature = temperature` and go straight to the last line. It seems to me like there are three attributes/properties created here: the Class attribute, `temperature`; the Instance attribute, `temperature`; and the `set_temperature` function which sets the attribute `_temperature`.

What I DO understand is that the last line (the assignment statement) must run the code `property(get_temperature, set_temperature)` which runs the functions `get_temperature` and `set_temperature` and intern sets the private attribute/property `_temperature`.

Moreover, if I run: `foo = Celsius(100)` and then `foo.temperature`, how is the result of `foo.temperature` coming from `temperature = property(get_temperature, set_temperature)` and thus `_temperature` AND NOT `self.temperature = temperature`?  Why even have `self.temperature = temperature` if `temperature = property(get_temperature, set_temperature)` gets ran every time the `foo.temperature` call is made?

More questions...

Why do we have two attributes with the same name (e.g. temperature) and how does the code know to retrieve the value of `_temperature` when `foo.temperature` is called?

Why do we need private attributes/properties an not just temperature?

How does `set_temperature(self, value)` obtain the attribute for parameter `value` (e.g. the argument that replaces `value`)?

In short, please explain this to me like a three year old since I have only been programming a few months.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: when `Celcius.temperature` is defined as a `property` it overrides the behaviour of the statement `self.temperature = ...` to instead call the setter function `set_temperature` so there is never an instance variable called `temperature` set.

Comment: How does it know to override the statement `self.temperature = temperature`?  Because they both have the same name, temperature?

Comment: yes, but more specifically because you have defined a descriptor in a class, when you do anything with the same name on an instance the descriptor handles what actually happens.  Exactly the same thing with methods, if you run `print(self.get_temperature)` it shows a `bound_method` object instead of the function itself, this is because functions are descriptors also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do Python properties work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193556/how-do-python-properties-work)

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  Mine is using a more real world example to illustrate these concepts.  I didn't even know what a descriptor was until you mentioned it.  I am a newbie and need more explanation given the answer you referenced.

Comment: Answering every one of your questions in a single answer means people don't get the credit they deserve for answering things, which is the entire point of providing answers here in the first place. On the other hand, a single person answering all of your questions using multiple answers means none of the answers can really be accepted as the correct one since they're all a part of the full answer. To answer most of your questions, anytime you see `x.temperature`, where `x` is an instance of `Celsius`, you're calling the getter or setter method of the property; nothing is "bypassed".

Comment: I'd recommend you take a look at [`__gettem__`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) and [`__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__), as they are closely related to this but maybe easier to understand  Then apply the same concept but with `x.temperature` instead of `x[1]`.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I can see that x.temperature is calling the getter or setter methods because it prints the statements in those fuctions--which was more or less stated in my post.  I have seen people on here ask REALLY vague questions that require going over many concepts to get to the final answer.  I was trying to be specific in my confusion AND my understanding--thinking that it might help someone pinpoint my issue.  Go ahead with the down vote though.  You only care about your SO points/status which upsets me. Hopefully not everyone on here is like you!!!

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen thank you for pointing me to those docs.  Unfortunately, I have read them and still am none the wiser.  I think my biggest hangup might be making the connection of the __init__ function which specifies the attribute `temperature` and what happens with that code when an instance is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we are first taught about classes/objects/attributes we are often told something like this:

> When you look up an attribute like `x.foo` it first looks to see if
>   `'foo'` is an instance variable and returns it, if not it checks if
>   `'foo'` is defined in the class of `x` and returns that, otherwise an
>   `AttributeError` is raised.

This describes what happens **most of the time** but does not leave room for *`descriptors`*.  So if you currently think the above is all there is about attribute lookup `property` and other descriptors will seem like an *exception to these rules.*

A descriptor basically defines what to do when looking up / setting an attribute of some instance, `property` is an implementation that lets you define your own functions to call when getting / setting / deleting an attribute.

When you do `temperature = property(get_temperature, set_temperature)` you are specifying that when `x.temperature` is *retrieved* it should call `x.get_temperature()` and the return value of that call will be what `x.temperature` evaluates to.

by specifying `set_temperature` as the `setter` of the property it states that when ever `x.temperature` is *assigned* to something it should call `set_temperature` with the value assigned as an argument.

I'd recommend you try [stepping through your code in pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=class%20Celsius%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__init__(self,%20temperature%20%3D%200%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.temperature%20%3D%20temperature%0A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20to_fahrenheit(self%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(self.temperature%20*%201.8%29%20%2B%2032%0A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20get_temperature(self%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print(%22Getting%20value%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20self._temperature%0A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20set_temperature(self,%20value%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20value%20%3C%20-273%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20raise%20ValueError(%22Temperature%20below%20-273%20is%20not%20possible%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print(%22Setting%20value%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self._temperature%20%3D%20value%0A%0A%20%20%20%20temperature%20%3D%20property(get_temperature,%20set_temperature%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%0Ax%20%3D%20Celsius(40%29%0Aprint(x.temperature%29&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false), it will show you exactly when `get_temerature` and `set_temperature` are called after which statements.

Comment: I would also like to reference a great article that helped me understand what what going on  [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/gist.github.com/ChrisBeaumont/5758381/raw/descriptor_writeup.ipynb).  Thanks!