# Getting error while running firefox browser in headless mode using python 3

Tags: python, selenium, headless, headless-browser

I am just trying to run this using headless browser i don't understand why it keeps throwing me the error even if i have provided  argument. Here i have read that it requires  argument to pass in options.add_argument() :- https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.options

Error :- TypeError: add_argument() missing 1 required positional argument: 'argument'

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


options = Options.add_argument('-headless')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options)
browser.get('https://intoli.com/blog/email-spy/')
browser.implicitly_wait(50)
heading = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="heading-breadcrumb"]/div/div/div/h1').text
print(heading)
browser.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an object Options before calling the property on it.
For more informations about how @property works, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193556/how-do-python-properties-work).

```
# create a new object
options = Options()
# calling the property (setter)
options.add_argument('-headless')
```

**Update** :
Furthermore, it seems that there are other problems with your code sample.
If you want to provide only firefox_options, you should do it as a keyword argument, so you must provide it explicitly:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
```

Comment: now it shows this error - TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not Options

Comment: Check my update. You should really follow some python guides and some selenium tutorials, as the errors that you make are very basic.

Comment: yeah i am learning & reading but some errors i don't understand. Thank you it is working now