# Mutable namedtuple?

Tags: python, namedtuple

Suppose I have:

```
from collections import namedtuple
NT = namedtuple('name', ['x'])
```

Can someone explain the difference between:

1. `NT.x = 3`
2. `var = NT(x=3)`

I can change `NT.x` to anything (mutable) but `var.x` is immutable. Why is that the case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NT` is not a namedtuple. `NT` is a class. Its *instances* are namedtuples.

You cannot reassign `x` on an instance. While you *can* technically mess with the `x` on the class, that will break attribute access for the `x` attribute of the instances, as the `x` on the class is a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) that instances rely on to implement the corresponding instance attribute.

Answer (score 2):

`namedtuple` is a class factory.

`NT(x=3)` gives you an instance of your freshly created class.

`NT.x =3` sets an attribute on the class itself.

Answer (score 2):

`NT.x` is an attribute of the *class* `NT`, not of an *instance* of that class:

```
>>> NT.x
<property object at 0x7f2a2dac6e58>
```

Its presence is just telling you that instances of `NT` have a property called `x`. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193556/how-do-python-properties-work).