# What is the difference between Methods and Properties for an object in python?

Tags: python, methods, properties

Suppose i have a data-frame object named as df, head() is a method that can be applied to df to see the first 5 records of the data-frame and df.size is a property to get the size of the data-frame.

For the property we are not using '()' as we used for a method. This was little confusing initially. 
Could anyone explain whats basic difference between a property and a method in python. I mean why we had to define size as a property for a dataframe, why not it was defined as a method which would have just returned the size of the data-frame.

Comment: possible duplicate [How do Python properties work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193556/how-do-python-properties-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I thought I'd link you to this answer because I think this explains it pretty well.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-the-difference-between-attributes-and-properties-in-python

If I had to explain it in my own words, properties are the 'attributes' of the object that have methods (get, set and delete).

So, if I understand correctly, *df.size* will be your property and then you need to define get, set and delete methods for this property. Also, I would recommend reading through the python class docs just to get proper usage and definitions.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

Here in the above example you mentioned, you can pass argument to `df.head()` function, where as you cannot pass arguments for properties.
for same above example, if you have written `df.head(20)` it would return first 20 rows.

Comment: Thank you! Does it mean, properties are defined when no argument are expected for some operation on an object? And if some arguments are expected we define a method?