# How to tell if a Python class member is decorated with `@property`

Tags: python

I'm subclassing `UUID` and I was trying to figure out if `UUID.hex` is a regular member or a method decorated with `@property`. I had to look at the source code to figure it out, which left me wondering if there was another way.

```py
>>> import uuid
>>> x = uuid.UUID('0000180000001000800000805f9b34fb')
>>> print([attr for attr in dir(x) if callable(getattr(x, attr))])
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__int__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
>>> print([attr for attr in dir(x) if not callable(getattr(x, attr))])
['__doc__', '__module__', '__slots__', '__weakref__', 'bytes', 'bytes_le', 'clock_seq', 'clock_seq_hi_variant', 'clock_seq_low', 'fields', 'hex', 'int', 'is_safe', 'node', 'time', 'time_hi_version', 'time_low', 'time_mid', 'urn', 'variant', 'version']
```

[The source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/46b16d0bdbb1722daed10389e27226a2370f1635/Lib/uuid.py#L334) is:

```py
    @property
    def hex(self):
        return '%032x' % self.int
```

It's a method decorated with `@property`. I was kinda expecting that `hex` would show up as `callable()`, but that's not the case. Is there any way I could tell that by examining the class or an object?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not callable because you can't write `instance.hex()`

Comment: Related: [How do python properties work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193556/how-do-python-properties-work)

Comment: @Alex, thanks, yes it does!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `property` decorator in Python takes a method and wraps it in an attribute that's defined on the *class*. Then instances of that class are smart enough to behave differently when the property is referenced.

Let's set up a simple class with one property and one field, as well as an instance of the class, for testing

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_field = "foo"

    @property
    def my_property(self):
        return "foo"

a = A()
```

Then, if we examine this class in the REPL, we see that `a.my_field` and `a.my_property` are both `"foo"`. More interestingly, `A.my_field` is an `AttributeError` and `A.my_property` is a `property` object (i.e. an instance of the `property` class. And that's exactly what we can use

```
def is_property(class_, name):
    try:
        return isinstance(getattr(class_, name), property)
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

If the name doesn't exist on the class, then return `False`, as it's definitely not a property. If it does, then check that it is an instance of the `property` class. Call it like

```
is_property(A, 'my_field')
is_property(A, 'my_property')
```

(Note we use the class, not an instance; and the field name is a string)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDPCoMwDIfvfYqwixZkl92EwTxsr1E6jVtB25JGmE/vrFv3T5Zbwvf9SOJHvjq7myZRdzoEqEohYK4GW1DKWMNK5QG7VpbLPFZst/2oWoNdA3vYtM5tHtrBk/NIPL5CZi7NfnMIeSCb9Aib8IaXfVQBVvf4lJjGlW2CsYG1rTG/IGtm@jYLSIlyUfFWo2eoZtCcB8YjkaNV6kl3AYXQ83VVLoXwZCznn@tVBWTpB5mU/4nUR2ia7g)

Comment: Your `is_property` function could just return `isinstance(getattr(class_, name, False), property)` ?